# Can't get this Angular Reactive Form(s) to work: databinding wrong, storing/getting data not properly populating the form, etc

Tags: angular, forms, data-binding, angular-reactive-forms

So this is an Angular 5 app. For this problem I've looked at the Angular.io basic documentation/exmaple app (which can be found here: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms ) but I can't seem to get it to work (properly) on my end :( . I also want to say I'm extremely new to Angular.

So I'll break this post down in explaining what I want, trying to show it with print screens (and in my commentary) and then showing the code for my component & service so that you can have a full picture of what I want, what I have and what could be wrong. Also, don't worry about the horrible layout everywhere, not of importance right now (it just has to work).

So it's an app that gets/creates stuff from/on Sharepoint, but if you don't know anything from Sharepoint that's not a problem to understand this problem.

First of all I have this page where you can login: [image]

A user will login on a specific Sharepoint tenant/site and then be redirected to my first view, where I want the user to be able to make Content Types in a form, dynamically. What I mean by this is that ideally, one empty one is shown and he can add "Content Types" as he pleases. A content type can be kind of seen as a "class" in normal programming.

Here is my Content Type view where I want the user to be able to make several: [image]

First of all, this generates some errors:

```
ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path: 'contentTypesInputFields -> 0 -> Name'
    at _throwError (forms.js:2432)
    at setUpControl (forms.js:2300)
    at FormGroupDirective.addControl (forms.js:6658)
    at FormControlName._setUpControl (forms.js:7308)
    at FormControlName.ngOnChanges (forms.js:7221)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:12365)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:13893)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:13836)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:14729)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:14670)
```

When I click on anything or type in any character/string anywhere, it seems to "cycle" through my controls (it can't seemingly find) and it eventually looks like this (like it should):

[image]

The errors it cycles through are the same as above, only this time also for 'Group' and 'ContentTypeInherit'. Some differences between this image and the previous: now it says "Content Type #1" and there's also my "inherit from Content Type:" label & select that shows (and the select is filled up).

I'm now going to click the button to add a new "test row", first image is what shows right after clicking the button, second image shows how it looks after typing in a couple of things (so it can cycle through the errors again):

First image:
[image]

Second image:
[image]

When I click my "Remove" button it should remove the "Content Type" fields it's clicked on, so if I click the "Remove" button under Content Type #2 it should remove that one and none other. Right now this button does nothing (but I tried coding it, see later).

Ok so now I'll share my entire code files:

My component HTML:

```
<form [formGroup]="contentTypeForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit($event)">
  <div formArrayName="contentTypesInputFields">
      <div *ngFor="let currentContentType of contentTypesInputFields.controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
        <h4>Content Type #{{i + 1}}</h4>
        <ul>
          <li class="form-group">
            <label>Content Type Name:</label>
            <input class="json-input form-control" type="text" formControlName="Name">
          </li>
          <li class="form-group">
            <label>Content Type Group:</label>
            <input class="json-input form-control" type="text" formControlName="Group">
          </li>
          <li class="form-group" *ngIf="contentTypeDropDown.length != '0'">
            <label>Inherit from Content Type:</label>
            <select class="json-input form-control" formControlName="ContentTypeInherit" *ngIf="!checkboxCTchecked">
              <option *ngFor="let ct of contentTypeDropDown" [value]="ct.name">{{ ct.name }}</option>
            </select>
            <!--
            <input class="json-input form-control" type="text" formControlName="ContentTypeInherit" *ngIf="checkboxCTchecked" placeholder="Cannot be left empty!">
            -->
          </li>
        </ul>
        <button type="button" (click)="removeContentTypeInputFields(currentContentType)">Remove</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <!--
        <button type="submit" [disabled]="contentTypeForm.pristine">Save</button>
        <button type="button" [disabled]="contentTypeForm.pristine" (click)="revertData()">Revert</button>
        -->
        <button type="submit">Save</button>
        <button type="button" (click)="revertData()">Revert</button>
      </div>
  </div>
</form>
<div>
  <button type="button" (click)="addContentTypeInputFields()">Click here to add a new test row!</button>
</div>
```

My component TS:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { DataServicesService } from '../data-services.service';
import { ContentType } from '../ContentType';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, FormArray } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-content-type-detail',
  templateUrl: './content-type-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./content-type-detail.component.css']
})
export class ContentTypeDetailComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

  contentTypeForm: FormGroup;

  contentTypeInputFieldsArrayOnLoad: ContentType[] = [
    {
      id: '',
      name: '',
      group: '',
      contentTypeInherit: ''
    }
  ];
  contentTypeInputFieldsArray: ContentType[] = this.contentTypeInputFieldsArrayOnLoad.slice();
  contentTypeDropDown: ContentType[] = [];

  checkboxCTchecked = false;

  constructor(
    private dataService: DataServicesService,
    private fb: FormBuilder
  ) {
    this.createForm();
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  ngOnChanges() {
    this.rebuildForm();
  }

  public createForm() {
    const tt2 = this.dataService.getData('ContentTypesDropDown');
    if (this.dataService.getData('ContentTypesDropDown') != null) {
      this.dataService.getData('ContentTypesDropDown').subscribe(
        res => this.contentTypeDropDown = JSON.parse(res)
      );
    }

    let data = null;
    if (this.dataService.getData('ContentTypes') != null) {
      this.dataService.getData('ContentTypes').subscribe(
        res => data = JSON.parse(res)
      );
    }

    if (data != null) {
      const arr = JSON.parse(data);
      this.contentTypeInputFieldsArrayOnLoad = arr;
      this.contentTypeInputFieldsArray = this.contentTypeInputFieldsArrayOnLoad.slice();
    }

    this.contentTypeForm = this.fb.group({
      // contentTypesInputFields: this.fb.array([])
      contentTypesInputFields: this.fb.array(this.contentTypeInputFieldsArrayOnLoad)
    });
    const tt = this.contentTypesInputFields;
  }

  public rebuildForm() {
    this.setContentTypes(this.contentTypeInputFieldsArray);
  }

  get contentTypesInputFields(): FormArray {
    return this.contentTypeForm.get('contentTypesInputFields') as FormArray;
  }

  public setContentTypes(ctArr: ContentType[]) {
    const contentTypeFGs = ctArr.map(x => this.fb.group(x));
    const contentTypeFormArray = this.fb.array(contentTypeFGs);
    this.contentTypeForm.setControl('contentTypesInputFields', contentTypeFormArray);
  }

  public onSubmit(event: Event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    this.saveData();
  }

  public addContentTypeInputFields(): void {
    this.contentTypesInputFields.push(this.fb.group(new ContentType('', '', '', '')));
  }

  public removeContentTypeInputFields(test: FormGroup): void {
    const index = this.contentTypeInputFieldsArray.indexOf(test.value['name']);
    if (index > -1) {
      this.contentTypeInputFieldsArray.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }

  public saveData() {
    const ct: ContentType[] = this.prepareSaveContentType();
    const json = JSON.stringify(ct);
    this.dataService.saveData('ContentTypes', json);
    this.contentTypeInputFieldsArray = ct;
    this.contentTypeInputFieldsArrayOnLoad = ct;
    this.rebuildForm();
  }

  public prepareSaveContentType(): ContentType[] {
    const formModel = this.contentTypeForm.value;

    // deep copy of form model input fields
    const inputFieldsDeepCopy: ContentType[] = formModel.contentTypesInputFields.map(
      // nog ke zien of "javascript literal object" goed is
      (ct: ContentType) => Object.assign({}, ct)
    );

    // return new contenttype array object containing a combination of original values
    // and deep copies of changed form model values
    const saveCT: ContentType[] = inputFieldsDeepCopy;

    return saveCT;
  }

  public revertData() {
    /*this.contentTypeInputFieldsArray = this.contentTypeInputFieldsArrayOnLoad.slice();
    const tt = this.contentTypeInputFieldsArray;*/
    this.rebuildForm();
  }

}
```

What I also want to achieve is that when I click on "save" button, it saves the data to a service (which just sets keys/values in a map). When I leave this component (for example to navigate to view "SiteColumns") and then when I come back, I want the component to check the service to see if, inside the service/map, there's a record with key 'ContentTypes, if so, fill in the amount of fields dynamically so that what the user saved, will be shown rather than an empty "Content Type" again.

Also, it doesn't seem to properly model bind my Content Type to the "*ngFor" it seems.

Can any of you see the problem (or presumably multiple problems)?